# Не работет отправка сообщений на почту C#

Tags: c#, smtp

Здравствуйте, подскажите как отправить сообщение на почту с Mail.ru аккаунта

Известен smtp-server **smtp.mail.ru**

Известен порт **465**

Вот код

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 465);

client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("andrej.vilyamov@mail.ru", "password");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

message.To.Add(email);
message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.From = new MailAddress("andrej.vilyamov@mail.ru");

message.Subject = "Тема";
message.Body = "ВЫ ВЫЙГРАЛИ МИЛЛИОН";

client.Send(message);
```

Но он не работает, почему? (отправляю на Яндекс)

Comment: Ошибка какая-нибудь возникает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий код, который отправляет письмо:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("myAddress@mail.ru"); // Адрес отправителя
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("clientAddress@yandex.ru")); // Адрес получателя
mail.Subject = "Заголовок";
mail.Body = "Письмо........................";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.mail.ru";
client.Port = 587; // Обратите внимание что порт 587
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("address@mail.ru", "password"); // Ваши логин и пароль
client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте добавить:

```
client.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: На [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237899/) предлагают еще попробовать вместе с этим параметром использовать порт 25.

Comment: На сайте mail.ru указано, что настройть SMTP нужно таким образом: порт-465, шифрование SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки с mail.ru на mail.ru в .Net Core можно использовать такой код:

```
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Port = 25;
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.Host = "smtp.mail.ru";
    client.Timeout = 300000;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@mail.ru", "frompassword");

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("from@mail.ru");
    mailMessage.To.Add("to@mail.ru");
    mailMessage.Body = "Разметка";
    mailMessage.Subject = "Заголовок";
    mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    mailMessage.BodyTransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    mailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    client.Send(mailMessage);
    client.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MailMessage mess = new MailMessage()
{
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    From = new MailAddress("ttt@bk.ru", "meSait"),
    Subject = "mess from sait",
    Body = "<div>mess from me</div>"
};
var From = new MailAddress("m111@bk.ru", "meSait");
MailAddress to1=new MailAddress("ttt@bk.ru");
mess.To.Add(to1 );
//mess.To.Add("khsd71@yandex.ru" );
mess.From = From;
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru"))
{
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("m111@bk.ru", "пароль для внешних приложений");
    smtpClient.Port = 587;// 465;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    //smtpClient.Host = "smtp.mail.ru";
    smtpClient.Send(mess);
    Console.WriteLine("mess OK!");
}
```

Comment: сегодня работает при такой настройке

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]