# Как с помощью класса SmtpClient отправить почту на яндекс?

Tags: c#, smtp, яндекс-почта

**UPD** Попробовал вариант, предложенный @sp7 но у меня не работает:

```
    public static void SendEmail(string to, string from, string boby, string subject)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from); // Адрес отправителя
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(from)); // Адрес получателя
        mail.Subject = "Заголовок";
        mail.Body = "Письмо........................";

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
        client.Port = 587; // Обратите внимание что порт 587
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, "TYTPAROL"); // Ваши логин и пароль

        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        }
        
    }
```

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException" в System.dll
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Неправильная последовательность команд. Отклик сервера: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first.
   в System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   в System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, Byte[] command, MailAddress from, Boolean allowUnicode)
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   в System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   в ExceptionHandler.Components.MailSender.SendEmail(String to, String from, String boby, String subject)
```

---

**UPD** Попробовал вариант, предложенный @sp7 для почты на mail.ru и все работает:

```
        from = "КакаятоПочта@mail.ru";
        client.Host = "smtp.mail.ru";
```

Comment: [Повтор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/699156/220553), нет?

Comment: там про мэйл ру вроде)

Comment: Меил, не меил - они все одинаковы. Но ладно, попробовал ваш код, все отравляет как надо. Такое впечатление, что у вас проблемы с интернетом, либо с доступом к яндексу. Вы случаем не из Украины это делаете, а то слышал там сервисы яндекста какие то блокируют. Попробуйте другую почту, возьмите Gmail к примеру или еще что (чисто для теста), со стороны кода проблем не каких, все должно отправлять. Проблема либо в соединение, либо вы что то еще нахимичили в программе...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у автора проблема с авторизацией - неверно указан логин или пароль, тот код, который я указал в ответе на вопрос работает исправно.

Comment: абсолютно этот же код для smtp.gmail.com выдает исключение System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное соединение, или подлинность клиента не была установлена. Отклик сервера: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: @Kluqwee что за магия у вас происходит? ) Люди же пишут, что код работает )

Comment: Ну видимо не очень надежный код)

Comment: @Kluqwee У вас точно логин и пароль верного формата? login@ya.ru пароль в нужном формате (регистре), ибо это реально магия.. Я сейчас по всячески издевался над кодом и не как не смог добиться того, что у вас.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я подобное исключение ловил только тогда, когда указывал неверный пароль нарочно.

Comment: @sp7 А да, неверный пароль дает подобное, либо и вовсе убирание строки Credentials.
Автор, если у вас неверный пароль вводится - тут мы нечем не поможем! Код полностью рабочий.

Comment: для двух ящиков то я не мог ошибиться) я же и с яндекса и с гмэйла уже попробовал

Comment: В общем зарегал в нагрузку еще емейл и на mail.ru.  все работает...  :))  Так что тут по любому что-то с яндексом и гмейлом не так.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример отправки письма:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("myAddress@yandex.ru"); // Адрес отправителя
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("clientAddress@mail.ru")); // Адрес получателя
    mail.Subject = "Заголовок";
    mail.Body = "Письмо........................";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
    client.Port = 587; // Обратите внимание что порт 587
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("address@yandex.ru", "password"); // Ваши логин и пароль
    client.Send(mail);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Исключение  Message "Неправильная последовательность команд. Отклик сервера: 5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first." string

Comment: Этот код точно работает? Как я уже писал выше, Яндекс не отправит письма на чужие адреса. Только самому себе писать можно. Это их защита от спама.

Comment: сам себе и пишу

Comment: @ОлегСолдатов только что используя этот код отправил письмо со своего ящика на Яндексе на ящик в Майл.

Comment: только скопировал ваш код как есть. исключение продолжает возникать

Comment: @Kluqwee, что за исключение, приведите детали?

Comment: @sp7, попробовал код. Да, работает. Возможно что-то другое мешает? Ошибка сервера "5.5.4 Error: send AUTH command first" указывает на проблему с авторизацией.

Comment: @Kluqwee, кстати, в качестве имени пользователя указываете полный адрес или только часть до "собаки"?

Comment: Полный с собакой итп. https://yadi.sk/i/qG741zPP3Lw3QC

Comment: @Kluqwee как правильно пишет данное исключение свидетельствует о проблеме с авторизацией. Вы у вас не правильно указан либо логин, либо пароль.

Comment: @ОлегСолдатов вы правильно  пишите, это указывает на проблему с авторизацией.

Comment: Минусы то за что? Предложенный вариант кода рабочий.

Comment: Незнаю, я плюсовал)

Comment: @Kluqwee как Вы в итоге справились с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 2):

Не хочу возрождать старый вопрос, но есть одно замечание:

указанные советы верны, но, чтобы они работали, нужно в яндексе включить вообще поддержку IMAP / SMTP.

То есть, по умолчанию, только что созданный ящик работает только через web-морду.

Потом вы в настройках включаете доступ для почтовых программ, что то вроде того, что на картинке:

[image: yandex mail settings]

И там, где подчеркнуто красным, Вы нажимаете на ссылку, создаёте *специальный отдельный пароль*, который не имеет никакого отношения к Вашему паролю для почтового ящика, и уже с этим паролем должна заработать отправка почты.

я это настраивал один раз, и я помню, что в самом начале, когда я только создал этот *отдельный пароль приложения*, я сначала подключил почтового клиента, и в этом клиенте у меня "всплыла" веб-страничка с каким то словами про OAuth2, и только потом, когда клиент уже работал, я стал отправлять письма программно.

Answer (score 1):

Были такие же проблемы. По факту представленные решения здесь - верные, однако проблема с неотправкой может быть в самом Яндексе. Следует проверить не подозревают ли вас на спам, а любой новый ящик с данными похожими на нереальные и без привязки телефона они подозревают по-умолчанию. Проверьте, отправляется ли у вас почта в принципе через веб-интерфейс Яндекса, возможно вас попросят ввести капчу - тут и проблемы.

P.S. 
Написал в помощь другим людям, которые наткнутся на этот вопрос, но решение им не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Я пользовался таким способом, особо проблем не возникало.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

public class SettingMessage
{
    public static void MessageSend()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var mess = new MailMessage())
            {
                var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.server.ru", 25); // smtp сервер, номер порта ["smtp.mail.ru",25);]
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Твоя почта", "Твой пароль");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                mess.From = new MailAddress("Твоя почта");
                mess.To.Add(new MailAddress("Кому отправлять"));
                mess.Subject = Environment.UserName;
                mess.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                mess.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                mess.IsBodyHtml = false;
                mess.Body = "Заголовок";
                try
                {
                    var attachfile = "С:\\file.txt"; // полный путь к Вашему файлу.
                    if (File.Exists(attachfile)) // Проверка есть ли файл на диске?!
                    {
                        var SF = new Attachment(attachfile);
                        mess.Attachments.Add(SF); // прикрепляем какой-нибудь файл.
                    }
                }
                catch { // тут лови исключения}
                client.Send(mess); // для отправки сообщения
               // mess?.Dispose(); // освобождение ресурсов
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант, при котором все заработало.

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("login@yandex.ru", "BR_Manager");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("login2@yandex.ru");
MailMessage m = new MailMessage(from, to);
m.Subject = "Тест";
m.Body = "Письмо-тест работы smtp-клиента";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login@yandex.ru", "password");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
await smtp.SendMailAsync(m);
Console.WriteLine("Письмо отправлено");
```

Важное замечание!

1. Заходим в почту -> "Настройки" -> "Все настройки" -> "Почтовые программы".
   Там ставим галочки на "Разрешить доступ по протоколу SMTP" и "Пароли приложений..."
2. Переходим в "Настройки"->"Безопасность"->"Пароли приложений".
   Там создаем пароль (не забудьте сохранить его, так как повторный просмотр невозможен) и именно ЕГО указываете в качестве пароля в `NetworkCredential`.

Answer (score -1):

Отправить возможно. Нужно включить SSL, а вот порт, как это ни странно, оставить по умолчанию - 25. К тому же письма должны отправляться строго на адрес, на который настроен SmtpClient. То есть, если вы с помощью сервера Яндекса попробуете отправить письмо на любой другой адрес, кроме своего, - оно не отправится.

Comment: var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.com", 25);
            
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, "Пароль");
            client.EnableSsl = true;  Message "Время ожидания 
     операции истекло." string

Comment: Время истекло при отработке кода из вопроса или после рекомендуемых изменений?

Comment: изменений, если я вас правильно понял и сделал что вы написали